# Using external variable in awk being passed to ssh in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, ssh

I'm trying to pass an external variable $time to an awk command that im running through an ssh to another machine.

```
time=...
pastusers=`ssh -n $host "last -n 10 | awk -v TIME=$time '{if ($7 > TIME) print $1}'"`
```

Is what I've done so far and the command Im passing to ssh works on its own but passing it through ssh causes it to fail.

I also tried..

```
pastusers=`ssh -n $host "last -n 10"` | awk -v TIME=$time '{if ($7 > TIME) print $1}'
```

but the ssh call does not return the new lines so awk doesn't get the right information.
Anyone have an idea to pass an external variable in what I tried first or how to keep the newline characters from the ssh call in what I tried second?

Comment: In awk, you don't use `$TIME`. That is not an error, but it's not likely to be what you wanted, which was `$7 > TIME`

Comment: The line "last -n 10 | awk -v TIME=$time '{if ($7 > $TIME) print $1}'" works as expected, that is not the problem. $time is not carried through when ssh is brought into the equation.

Comment: Try printing $TIME inside the awk script and see if its what you expect. (In awk, `$` is a prefix operator whose operand is an integer; the value is the indexed field. If the operand is larger than the number of fields, the value is just the empty string, or 0 in an arithmetic context.)

Comment: I see, thanks for the insight! My problem still persists though :(.

Comment: Updated main question to reflect rici's help and another thing I tried that failed in a different manner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the following test.sh:

```
#! /bin/bash
host=$1
mytime=$2
pastusers=`ssh -n $host "last -n 10" | awk -v TIME=$mytime '{if($7>TIME) print $1}'`
echo $pastusers
```

When I run `bash test.sh <some_valid_host> 20:00` it prints a list of users as expected, all in the same line. Those being in the same line is also expected.

If you have a file test.txt like:

```
abc
def ghi
```

Running

```
words=`cat test.txt`; echo $words
```

will print `abc def ghi` all in same line. This is the expected behavior.

Comment: Thanks.. I see I misplaced a ` in my second attempt.. hah.